# Angular JS/ Html queries on Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im working on a simple todo app tutorial online based on: 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html

What if I wanted a database where instead of a fixed list like in the example, there would be a store where users can input their list dynamically, with room for edit and comments on their tasks outstanding?

- a paragraph of text
- user name noted
- timestamp

It would then appear as a todo list that upon clicking, would open up to be editable and able to add more comments to it?

I have followed a couple of tutorials but all of them use fixed data sets. 
I did some research and got the below snippets, my understanding of Angular is still weak so am not exactly clear how the codes work.

Something isnt working and Im not sure why. Can anyone explain and help? 
Specifically on params and how id comes into play, as well as the convention of url routing, like #/something.html etc.

The tutorial has firebase back end but if you have any better suggestions (like server and back end language), please let me know. Ive seen tutorials using JSON but again, not sure how that works.

**For app.js**

```
.state('bucket.list.detail',{ 
    url: '/list/:itemId',
    views: {
        'bucket-list-detail':{
            templateUrl: 'templates/bucket-list-detail.html',
            controller: 'DetailController'
        }
    }

})
```

**For controller.js**

```
.controller('DetailController', function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $window, $firebase){
    $scope.item = items.get($stateParams.itemId);
})
```

**For the view file, bucket-list-detail.html**
(I just typed in some trash lines to test the code)

```
<p>{{ item.item }}</p>

<p>
    <a class="button button-small icon ion-arrow-left-b" 
    href="#/bucket/list"> Main List </a>
</p>
```

Comment: How do initiate items?

Comment: Where do you have `items` defined?  Typically you'd be calling firebase or some other factory you have in order to get the item.

Answer (score 0):

First in your question you have `items.get` in your controller but nowhere did you define `items`.  Since `$firebase` is probably a factory of some kind you will probably need to either use that or build some service that is getting your data (via firebase or however).

As an example, I've built a sample todo app using .NET (web api) and Ionic that you can see the source code on [github](https://github.com/sbosell/kpensar-tarea-di/blob/master/Tarea.MobileApp/js/controllers.js).  The overall strategy for firebase should be similar.

I have a route like this, very similar to yours.  This is for the details view:

```
.state('tab.tarea-detail', {
  url: '/tarea/:tareaId',
  views: {
    'tab-friends': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/_detalle.html',
      controller: 'TareaDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

The state param will contain `tareaId`.

The list view has an ngRepeat with a link containing the id of a todo (tarea in spanish).

```
  <ion-item ng-repeat="tarea in tareas track by $index" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/tarea/{{tarea.Id}}">{{tarea.Nombre}} {{tarea.Desc}} 
  <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="tareaEliminar(tarea)">
  </ion-item>
```

And my controller which will receive the id and call a service:

```
.controller('TareaDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, tareaService) {
    //tareaService is just a wrapper for my ajax stuff, you could call firebase here or you could just use firebase
    tareaService.obtener($stateParams.tareaId).then(function (data)
    {
        $scope.tarea = data;
    });
})
```

The service piece is just calling $http.  This is a part of the service:

```
    obtener: function (id)
    {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http.get(url + '/api/tareadata/obtener/' + id).success(function (data)
        {
            d.resolve(data);

        }).error(function (data, error)
        {
            d.reject();
        });
        return d.promise;
    }
```